# How to fill in input with "require" using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to java script. I have created an input which is requires the user to input some text to enable the submit button.

```
<input class="param" name="test" id="test" required ng-model="test">
```

How can I fill in the input text box using Java Script so I can submit the form (as if the user has entered the text). Currently, when I use for example the following script to update the value, the submit button on the form is not active.

```
document.getElementById("test").value =1
```

Comment: It's best to explicitly specify the `type` of the input.

Comment: @jmargolisvt  I used = for updating the value through JS but the submit button is still disabled. However, entering text using the keyboard enables the submit button.

Comment: Can you please post your HTML and JS?

Comment: When I test it it actually works, perhaps there is something else going on that you did not specify

Comment: The `required` attribute is not supported on Safari.

Comment: All I want is to trigger the same event as if a user enters the text through JS. Mere changing the value does fulfill the required condition.

Comment: your question doesn't make sense to me. Add more code

Comment: I update the input value on page load and upon click of submit, the required attribute still works. `window.onload = function () { updateValue(); }

        function updateValue() {
            document.getElementById("test").value = 1;
        }`

Comment: what **condition** are you talking about here?  the only code you have is an assignment (`=`), not a condition (`==`).  besides this, you *appear* to be using angularjs (`ng-model`), and `document.getElementById` with angular is a ***very bad practice.***

Comment: Based on my previous comment, please [edit] your question with more information.  There is a **very common** pattern for achieving what you are describing, assuming you are using AngularJs;  it involves both your HTML and your JavaScript (the controller, specifically), so please add those to the [edit].  A [mcve] using http://plunkr.co or something similar is also good.

Comment: This is part of a platform that  the whole html and java script are not available to me. But to put more clearly, how can I submit a form that has required attribute through JS? (as if a user has entered a value)

Comment: you don't have to supply the *exact* javascript, but you should show a **more complete example** that shows all of the pieces that are used.  The form, the button, the input, the controller (in case of angularjs) are all pieces of the whole puzzle, and you can't show someone how to put a puzzle together with missing pieces.  I could create a couple pieces based on what *I think you might be doing*, but they probably won't fit.   As I have said more than once, you seem to be trying to use plain JavaScript to do something that your framework (AngularJs) has the ability to do for you.

Comment: reading your question again, I think I misunderstood completely what you are trying to do.  I attempted to provide a few examples, but now I am questioning the examples I wrote, and still think you need to confirm if you are trying to use AngularJs or not before I can even make another attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Could you update the attribute that ng-model is bound to?  That should apply the value to the text field correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have created this example code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function updateValue() {
      document.getElementById("test").value = 'test';
    }
    window.onload = function () {
      updateValue();
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="test" name="test" required>
  <input type="submit" value="Okay">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is [what Phani Kumar M and Claies were asking for](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I tested it on Windows 10 in Firefox 55.0.3 and Chrome 60.0.3112.113. In both browsers it works correctly. The form can be submitted without adding anything to the field.

Others can check other platforms. As mentioned, the `required` attribute will not work in Safari.

Your problem is somewhere else. I don't know anything about AngularJS, which you seem to be using without even mentioning it, but it might be there.